# Who will see my likes in Twitter

Tags: twitter, tweets

I don't exactly know, when I like a tweet in Twitter, who can see it. Is it all of my followers? Or just a fraction of them will see the posts I liked? For instance, in the case of "mention" all of my followers will see my mentions, or for "reply" all the people who follow me and the receipant of my reply will see it. But I couldn't find anything about those who can see my likes when I googled it.
In other word, if 100 people are following me, do all of them see my likes in Twitter?

Comment: This does not appear to be a programming question.

Comment: @AndyPiper this is a challenging question I encountered while I was doing social network analysis over Twitter data

Answer (score 1):

If they look at the tweet in particular, everyone who has not blocked or silenced you. That can be accessed via the API too.

Comment: I didn't fully understand your answer. Do you mean if I follow 10 people, all of them will see what I liked in their time line?

Comment: If your account is public, anyone with access to the web and any developer with access to the API will be able to see that.

Answer (score 1):

Your likes are public. Just add `/likes` to the end of your user URL.

For example, you can see all of mine at https://twitter.com/edent/likes

Anyone logged in to Twitter can see your likes unless you have blocked them.

Whether your friends see your like in their timeline depends on Twitter's algorithm.